# NCalc custom function referencing a Guid

Tags: c#, guid, ncalc

I'm trying to use NCalc to parse some formula from JSON files.

However sometimes I'm needing to reference another object via GUID and get that objects formula:

```
public class FooObject
{
  NCalc.Expression expression;
  double Value;
  public void SetValue()
  {Value = (double)expression.Evaluate()} //this throws "Value was either too large or too small for a Double."

  public FooObject()
  { expression = new NCalc.Expression("TechData(b8ef73c7-2ef0-445e-8461-1e0508958a0e)")}
    expression.EvaluateFunction += NCalcFunctions;
  }
}

public static void NCalcFunctions(string name, FunctionArgs args)
{
  if (name == "TechData") //breakpoint shows we never get this far
  {
    Guid techGuid = new Guid(args.Parameters[0].ToString());
    TechSD techSD = _staticData.Techs[techGuid]; //this returns an TechSD object that matches the given guid.
    args.Result = techSD.DataExpression;//returns an NCalc expression from the techSD
  }
}
```

`SetValue()` throws an exception (*Value was either too large or too small for a Double*), and the custom function never gets called.

I'm suspecting it's trying to parse the GUID. Would this be correct? Is what I'm trying to do possible with NCalc? is there a better tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this NCalc expression:

```
TechData(b8ef73c7-2ef0-445e-8461-1e0508958a0e)
```

GUID `b8ef73c7-2ef0-445e-8461-1e0508958a0e` is not parsed as a string (note there aren't single quotes), NCalc will then try to parse that expression as

- `b8ef73c7` variable name, undefined.
- `-` subtraction operator.
- `2ef0` syntax error, it's not an identifier (it starts with a number) and also it's not a valid number (because of `e` it'll try to parse it as `double` in scientific notation but it's not valid).
- ...

You have to use quotes:

```
TechData('b8ef73c7-2ef0-445e-8461-1e0508958a0e')
```

Now NCalc will correctly parse this expression and your handler may simply:

```
var techGuid = Guid.Parse((string)args.EvaluateParameters()[0]);
```

Comment: Ah! Excelent! single quotes! Thankyou! (though args.Parameters[0].ToString() is returning a string *with* the single quotes, and (string)args.Parameters[0]) does not work either. still this is a much easier problem to figure out :-)

Comment: Just use `args.EvaluateParameters()[0]` instead of `args.Parameters[0]` (they're raw unevaluated expressions).

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't notice the EvaluateParameters. that's a lot nicer than using Trim.